# Disappearing tiles depending on the zoom

Tags: qgis, zoom, centos, tile-server

I'm working on a CentOS 6.8 tiles server hosted in a VM and I observed some disappearing tiles depending on my zoom level in QGIS 2.16, I don't know where it comes from...

Here are some pictures of my screen on which I'll progressively zoom in :

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I get the same result on some others countries while others works perfectly...

I'm using QuickMapServices with TMS protocol.

Comment: It looks like some database requests have not been answered, so only the coastline is rendered from the shapefile. I don't think it is a QGIS or tile-server problem, but one of mapnik andt the database access.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you have some ideas about how I can fix this ?

Comment: You can try pre-rendering the tiles, and investigate the result with a simple Openlayers or leaflet web site. And look out for renderd error logs.

Comment: I just found the solution, it's about cache in QGIS. I turned off `use the cache rendering if possible`, it's a bit slower but all the tiles are downloaded correctly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution, it's about cache in QGIS. I turned off use the cache rendering if possible, it's a bit slower but all the tiles are downloaded correctly now.